# Spring Message Listener Names

Tags: spring, jms, listener

I have created several spring 4.1.6 @JmsListener methods for receiving messages from queues.  I would like to get the list of listener names for admin purpose:

```
    @JmsListener(
        destination = "${jms.destination.name}"
        , containerFactory = "myJmsContainerFactory"
        , id ="myListener")
    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received <" + message + ">");
    }
```

and I want to display the id/name of the listeners for admin purposes.  I can stop and start the listeners with the JmsListenerEndpointRegistry, but can't see how to get the name of the specific listeners.

```
    JmsListenerEndpointRegistry registry = context.getBean(org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.class);

    Collection<MessageListenerContainer> listeners = registry.getListenerContainers();
    MessageListenerContainer mlc = registry.getListenerContainer("myListener");
    System.out.println("Running" + mlc.isRunning());

    mlc.stop();
```

In debug the Collection can be seen as a Collections$UnmodifiableCollection with a LinkedHashMap that has the listener id ,myListener in this case, as the key value of the LinkedHashMap

Answer (score 1):

This question was quite old, but I solved it this way:

```
Set<String> listenerContainerIds = registry.getListenerContainerIds();
for (String id : listenerContainerIds) {
    MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = registry.getListenerContainer(id);
    ...
}
```

I got the reference to the MessageListenerContainer und via getListenerContainerIds, I got the name of the ID to the reference.

Hope this helps...